# While clicking the button Array append or array push inside for loop using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects, array-push

I have an idea for making single array value dynamically created while clicking button
this is code i run on local,

```js
function clearr()
{
      var exp ='25';  
      let btn = document.getElementById("clear");
      let val = btn.value;
      var d=0;
for($i=0; $i<=3;$i++){
  if(val=='C')
    { 
       if(d==1){
            d=d;
        }else if(d===undefined){
             d=0;
           // alert(d);
            // return false;
        }else{
            d=d;
        }
      const Vio=[];
     Vio.push(exp);
     console.log(Vio);
     d++;
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: What's your question? Also, your code doesn't make any sense. If your goal is to append an element to an existing array, that's not what it's doing. The `Vio` list is always being reset in your loop, so when all is said and done, you'll print out an array with a single element...

Comment: this code, on button,  
<input id="clear" class = "btn" type = "button" value = "C" onclick = "clearr()" >
if all done, outside for loop, no return

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I understand what you're going for, and it looks like you're overthinking things. To have the button append to an array, the array needs to be defined at a global scope, not local to the function, as you have it. Furthermore, the list can't be `const`, as that means you cannot modify it.

For this simple case, you don't need any `if` conditionals. All your function needs to do is retrieve the current value of the button and push the value onto the array.

I'll whip up a snippet to demonstrate. For this, the input will come from a text field rather than a button. Clicking "Add" will call the `add` function, which appends the text field's value onto the array `some_list`. Clicking "Print" will print out the list's contents to the console.

```js
var some_list = []

function add() {
    // Get a handle to the text field
    var element = document.getElementById("textfield")
    
    // Add the current text field's value to an array
    some_list.push(element.value)
}
```

```html
<input id ="textfield" type = "text"></input>
<!-- This button will cause the value in the above text field to be added to a running list-->
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
<br><br>
<!-- Print out the array-->
<button onclick="console.log(some_list)">Print</button>
```